Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function - why?
I'm trying to understand why this error is appearing, I couldn't find similarities to other questions around here.
function decreaseQty(item) {
  if (item.qty > 1) {
    const updatedItems = cartItems.map((i) => {
      if (i.product._id === item.product._id) {
        i.qty--;
      }
      return i;
    });

    setCartitems(updatedItems);
  }
}

function removeItem(item) {
  const updatedItems = cartItems.filter((i) => {
    if (i.product._id !== item.product._id) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  setCartitems(updatedItems);
}


You forgot to return false in callback function. Callback of filter function should return either true or false.
function removeItem(item) {
  const updatedItems = cartItems.filter((i) => {
    if (i.product._id !== item.product._id) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  setCartitems(updatedItems);
}

Same for map in this way
function decreaseQty(item) {
  if (item.qty > 1) {
    const updatedItems = cartItems.map((i) => {
      if (i.product._id === item.product._id) {
        return {...i, qty: i.qty - 1};
      }
      return i;
    });

    setCartitems(updatedItems);
  }
}


You should use the callback variant of the state setter to grab the current items and filter those.
Also, a filter function simply needs to return a boolean, so just return your condition.
function removeItem(item) {
  setCartitems(prevItems =>
    prevItems.filter((i) => i.product._id !== item.product._id));
}

Same with your mapping function, but make sure you return a new object when modifying (immutability):
function decreaseQty(item) {
  setCartitems(prevItems => prevItems.map((currItem) => {
    if (currItem.product._id !== item.product._id) return currItem;
    return { ...currItem, qty: Math.max(currItem.qty - 1, 1) };
  }));
}

